# Jupyter Notebook command prompt import error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to start up the Jupyter Notebook application and it is not working at all.

I've tried opening it from the windows menu, a command prompt window opens up and closes.

I also tried running it from the anaconda command prompt and it gives me the following error:

````
(base) C:\Users\GG>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GG\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\GG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py) ```

Any idea on how to fix this?
````

Comment: You likely have a version mixup and/or incorrectly configured PATH which includes an environment outside of your conda. You can either fix the PATH issue or try to upgrade `zmq` to a common version across all environments.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I fix the PATH issue or upgrade the `zmq` to a common version?

Comment: One way would be to uninstall it the same way you installed it and install again. You could also try installing https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_app (beta).